# send graphical e-mail alert with details from the shell script

Tags: gnuplot

I have written a shell script which sends me number of connections in the database server for every 2 hours to my e-mail id. Now I want to plot a graph using those details and send a graphical diagram to the e-mail as alert. I am trying to gnuplot for that, but I am not sure how I can do that in the shell script? Can anybody suggest me how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Very easy with a pipe redirection:

```
awk -f myscript < input > data.dat
gnuplot << END 
set term pdf
set output "data.pdf"
plot "data.dat"
unset term 
END
mutt me -a data.pdf -s "Stats" < "Stats for the day"
```